# discord.py - How to write data to a JSON file when my bot joins a server

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to make a settings file for all of the servers my bot is in. Every time a bot joins a server, it gets the guild ID and some values and puts it into a JSON file for features to work. I've tried fixing it for a solid hour and I don't get **any** errors. It doesn't write to the file at all. I've looked around this entire website to figure out why the code isn't writing to the file, but all I got was errors. Or, it just didn't write. Does anyone know how to fix this issue? Thanks.

I also tried several file types, and they mostly didn't work. Any help?

### Code

```
@bot.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    sdb = open('database\\serverdb.json', 'r')
    data = {}
    if not str(guild.id) in sdb:
        data[str(guild.id)] = {}
        data[str(guild.id)]['test3'] = 0
        data[str(guild.id)]['test2'] = 1
        data[str(guild.id)]['test'] = 1
        print("added")
    else:
        print("found")
    print("workie")
```

Comment: Are there any outputs at all? What about your print statements? If they don't run at all, it may be that you have some intents off or it might be another problem.

Comment: Can you point to a specific line in the code you've provided you feel should write anything to the actual file? You create a structure named `data` and potentially write data to it, but you never really do anything to write the data back to the JSON file in question. You're also opening the file in read-only mode (`r`), so it's unclear how you've drawn the conclusion that you should even be able to write to this file in the first place given your current configuration.

Comment: If you are getting no errors, this should be an issue that it is not triggering this event at all. You can try to add a print statement to affirm this, but likely you have issues with Intents like Blue Robin had mentioned.

Comment: The print statements do show up, it just doesn't apply the edits

Comment: Then this is a duplicate of how to write JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Reading a JSON file

It is preferred that you use the `with` keyword to automatically close it, or else you will have to close the file with `close()`.

```
import json
async def func():
    with open("file.json", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        data = json.load(f)
```

Now `data` will be treated as a dictionary.

### Dumping a JSON file

Or in other words saving the data, once you have edited `data`, you have to save it back into the file with `json.dump`.

```
def dump_json(data):
    with open("file.json", "w+") as f:
        json.dump(data, f)
```

Read more in [open()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) and [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html).

Comment: There's not enough information to determine whether or not OP has an unrelated error to json saving. If it is about json saving, then it may be considered a duplicate.

Comment: My apologies for not clarifying for more information with the OP. But concerning the question at hand, "writing data into a JSON file", my answer solves it. I do not deny that this is likely a duplicate. I will work on this moving forward. Cheers, Raymus

Comment: I believe I was a bit too harsh with the downvote. Either way, the answer itself is correct.